# Analysis of factors that have impact on explanatory variable

Tags: random-forest, logistic-regression

for my master thesis I am analyzing stock outs. I want to find out what factors played key roles that finally led to a stock out or (will) lead to a high stockout probability, for example late production, too long quality checks, late supplier etc.

What method is best to use here? I was thinking about random forest or logistic regression, but maybe there is even something better?

Thanks